# Facebook Logout URL vs. Session_Destroy

Tags: facebook, url, authentication

Is there a difference or advantage between the Facebook URL or the session_destroy.

I have incorporated the Facebook SDK PHP 3.1.1 on my website storing data for file uploads. For the file uploads I create $_SESSION id's...

The logout URL does not provide for additional $_SESSION params to be deleted.

So the question is... Can I just call a function (i.e. session_destroy.php) and kill all or is there a relevant need for the Facebook Logout URL?

If there is how can I incorporate a session_destroy() when the Logout URL is called?

Answer (score 2):

It's against their TOS

> Your website must offer an explicit "Log Out" option that also logs the user out of Facebook.

http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: so the big button that says Logout, calling a session_destroy() effectively login out of every website wouldwork

Comment: @Lucky8Media: session_destroy() do not log you out from Facebook

Comment: I don't want to log out of facebook. I want to log out of MY website and session_destroy() clears all cookies from the web browser, is my understanding.

Comment: @Lucky But it's against to their tos not to give them "log out from fb" button